# In IE11 - Windows 7, web page files are being downloaded each time the page is refreshed instead of retrieving from cache

Tags: caching, internet-explorer-11

When we load our web page in IE11 on Windows 7, hit F12 and refresh the page, in the Network tab we see that each time we refresh the page, files are downloaded instead of getting it from cache. The Result column displays "200". This creates a performance issue. We turned off the "Always refresh from server" option then we see that for multiple files in the Result column it displays "304" as grayed out. Since we had to manually turn off the "Always refresh from server" option, how do we get this to work for the end user who is using IE11 on Windows 7?

In Internet Options - General - Settings, the 'Check for newer versions of stored pages' is set to 'Automatically'.

Comment: Please explain more details about the files you want to cache? static file or script?You could refer to [asp.net caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178597(v=vs.100)) to know more about the cache.

Comment: Files retrieved from cache (we see this in IE11-Windows 10) are .js, image and css files. Pages in our asp .net web application are taking more time to load in IE11-Windows 7 compared to IE11-Windows 10. Could this be because .js, image, css files are not being retrieved from cache? Any way to check if files are retrieved from cache in IE11-Windows 7?